# Help evaluating an integral of a Bessel function times an irrational.

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm looking for some help integrating the following,

$$\int_a^b \frac{x}{\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}} \, J_0(kx) \, dx$$

I've found similar integrals in the tables of Gradstein and Ryzhik where the irrational term is $\sqrt{c-u^2}$. I can complete the square and $u$ sub but I end up with the argument of the Bessel function being a sum of $u$ and a constant, and I do not know how to proceed. Further, I am not sure if I can transform the integral limits to match the expression in the tables. I'm not confident that there is even a closed form expression for this integral.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to integrate this not using tables? What is the standard method used for integrating functions like this?

Comment: The integrand diverges at $b$ and $a$.  Why would the integral be finite?

Comment: Gradstein and Ryzhik have a nearly identical integral where the irrational term is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ with bounds 0 and 1 that is non-infinite. That's a good point though. This integral is physically motivated, it comes from a calculate of the gravitational potential of a thin washer assuming the radial mass density of the disk is inversely proportional to the Kepler velocity. Given it's physical motivation I assumed it wasn't divergent.

Comment: While there may no be a closed form, it is very easy to obtain an infinite series for the integral. Use $$J_0(z)=\sum_{m\ge0}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!^2}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2m}.$$

Comment: Unfortunately, I will need to integrate $k$ from 0 to $\infty$ after evaluating this integral so I don't think this series will be much help? I can look into it further.